# How to keep hub connection alive in C# till the task is completed

Tags: c#, signalr

I am Sending Emails using send-Grid API. It about 10000 mails.
i am using hub to for notification to check then mail status and display it to user. Hub gets reconnected every 3 minutes. And the process starts all over again.

how to keep  same hub connection alive till the task is done.

my Code

```
--> In js

         ///Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var progress = $.connection.progressHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        progress.client.AddProgress = function (message, percentage, delivered, error) {
            console.log(message);
            ProgressBarModal("show", delivered, error, message);
            $("#ProgressMessage").css("width", percentage + "%");
            //$('#ProgressMessage').width(percentage+"%");
            $('#ProgressMessage').text(percentage + "%");
            if (percentage == "100%") {
                ProgressBarModal();
            }
        };

        $.connection.hub.start({ pingInterval: null }).done(function () {
            var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
        });

        $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
            toastr.warning('Warning - Connection Is Slow...');
            //alert("connectionSlow");
            console.log("connectionSlow");
        });

        $.connection.hub.reconnecting(function () {
            toastr.info('Connection Reconnection..');
            //alert("Reconnecting Hub ");
            console.log("Reconnecting Hub ");
        });

        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            toastr.error('Connection Disconnected...');
            if ($.connection.hub.lastError) {
                alert("Disconnected. Reason: " + $.connection.hub.lastError.message);
            }
        });
```

--> In Global.asax

GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(5.00);
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = null;

---> in C# i call the hub in for each loop to display the notification for each mails send and its status.

Comment: Please add your source code to get the better and perfect answer!

Comment: i have update my code.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to change timeout and keepalive settings. something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 110 seconds for a
    // response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
    // make the client reconnect.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);

    // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
    // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    // For transports other than long polling, send a keepalive packet every
    // 10 seconds. 
    // This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

The entire Understanding and [Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeoutkeepalive) is probably relevant to your question.

Comment: I did Tried that. But i got error message as   Disconnected. Reason: The client has been inactive  and it has exceeded the inactivity timeout of 30000 ms. Stopping the connection.